# User creating case record not being able to view the case

Tags: case, security, org-wide-defaults, owner

I have a user who has created a new Case Object record. The user has Read/Write/Create access for his profile for Case. The org-wide settings for Case is Private.  The Case owner is a different user(Changed later).

The user who has created the record is not being able to access and it is showing insufficient privilege.

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong. Also is there any way to give access to the creating user after the owner has been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once ownership changes, it's entirely possible the user won't have access to the case. If you wanted to make sure they still had access, consider building a Process Builder action to add them to the Case Team for the Case. This would allow them to retain read-only or write access after the ownership change.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any supporting salesforce documentation saying that the  case will not be visible by the creator? That would be really helpful @sfdcfox

Comment: @Rimii The only "evidence" is really a lack thereof. There's lots of sharing features: ownership, role hierarchy, sharing rules, manual sharing, team sharing, territory management sharing, implicit sharing, and account sharing, but "creator" is not one of those sharing features. Being the creator of a record does not grant any special privileges to the user.

Comment: Another problem which I am having is that, even when I create the process builder, that will only be for when I am creating or editing, the records. However I have lots of previously created records, for which the users will loose visibility.

Comment: @Rimii You would have to export the list of records you want to update and add team members to those cases. There's really not much you can do about retroactively applying the process builder.